# AWS SES/WorkMail: Dynamically create mailboxes that forward to external addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

I'm building a service where the end users can create organizations. Other users may then be added to the organization, and each organization may have a number of administrators.
The service is built on AWS.

Now, when an organization is created, I'd like to automatically create an email address corresponding to the organization, and forward all messages sent to this address to the external e-mail addresses of the administrators of the organization.

So for example let's say the domain of my service is `example.com`, and Alice (`alice@somewhere.com`) creates an organization called `Foobar`. She also adds Bob (`bob@somewhere.com`) as a second administrator.

I'd then like to register `admins-foobar@example.com` as a valid mailbox, and whenever someone sends e-mail to this address, it should be forwarded to `alice@somewhere.com` and `bob@somewhere.com`, ideally also with the reply path set to the original sender, so that Alice and Bob can answer support questions.

The purpose of this is to have a single point of contact for support issues etc for all the users within an organization.

I've used AWS SES and AWS WorkMail in the past, mostly for transactional mail, notifications and for statically created incoming mailboxes for support etc, but I cannot seem to find if what I want is possible to do through the AWS SDK.

First of all, I'm not sure if what I want to do requires AWS WorkMail at all or if this is somehow possible to solve using AWS SES and trigger rules, but I first looked at WorkMail. The AWS WorkMail SDK enables creating users and enabling mailboxes for them through the SDK, and users are grouped into organizations. However, I cannot find a way to *create* organizations through the SDK, only through the AWS web console!

Second, I cannot find how I can programmatically set up e-mail rules for forwarding e-mail sent to the created users' mailboxes.

Is this possible at all using AWS services?

Comment: Workmail doesn't seem to be supposted very well through the SDKs/API. You can't even create a new workmail organization or add domain aliases. So that's likely a dead end. I'd go with an SES/incoming lambda trigger approach for this